# Angular binding in function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular 1. I have the following markup:

```
ng-mouseover="myFunction(myobj.value)" ng-show="myobj.value"
```

I have the following object declared in my controller:

```
$scope.myobj = {
  value: false
};
```

And then my function:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(obj) {
  obj = true;
  console.log($scope.myobj);
}
```

I'm expecting it to set $scope.myobj.value to true when I hover over the element but it doesn't. It seems to bind it correcty so it picks it up that it's an object but it's not referencing the $scope one. How do i go about doing this so it sets the $scope one correctly?

Comment: You can pass the object directly in your function....refer my answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

Instead do this:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(obj) { // passed value false;
  $scope.myobj.value = !obj; // !false === true
  console.log($scope.myobj); // outputs { value : true }
};
```

What you did?

`obj = true;` this one declares a global object with a boolean value `true` and it has no effect on your code. Instead you have to update the `$scope.myobj` with the opposite passed value in the method as with `!obj`.

Comment: What is the value he's passing in can change, like if he had two mouseovers affecting `$scope.myobj` and `$scope.otherobj`?

Comment: Well in that case OP has to put in the isolated scope.

Comment: Instead, Inside the `function(obj) {obj.value = true } `

Comment: I have multiple areas in my markup that will use this function with different values within the $scope myobj so I wanted to avoid explicitly referencing the $scope object in the function and for angular to automatically bind it instead. I know I could also pass obj as a string then split it and loop over each item in $scope but I was hoping for a clean 1 liner that angular would automatically do.

Comment: @Srigar that also won't help because in obj.value cause error as obj is not  an object in the global scope.

Comment: @user1157885 whatever you have posted anyone can answer the same as i tried to answer. Yet if you make your question a bit more clear then most probably we can help you with that.

Comment: @Jai In html we can write like this `ng-mouseover="myFunction(myobj)"`. Javascript works under prototype rit.

Comment: @Srigar That is other thing. Here you have to update your model which lies in the $scope object to let angular know/aware that something is happend. while what you are suggesting is outside of angular and in that case you have to run the digetst cycle manually.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to set your scope object is wrong as you are passing a value type to your function,

for ex: if the value of myobj.value is true/false..you are simpling passing this value and not the reference of this variable.

You should set the value like below

```
$scope.myFunction = function(obj) {
   $scope.myobj = true;
  console.log($scope.myobj);
}
```

**OR**

Just pass myObj like below

```
ng-mouseover="myFunction(myobj)" ng-show="myobj.value"
```

and then set the value the way you are setting like below

```
$scope.myFunction = function(obj) {
   obj.value = true;
  console.log($scope.myobj);
}
```